# How to write Unit test case for this method?

Tags: java, junit

```
public String createUser() {

    Session session = HibernateUtility.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(this);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return "accountCreated";

}
```

How to write Unit test case for this method?

Comment: what do you want to test exactly? Not much point of testing if some library methods work or not... If you want to test behavior of the createUser() method, just create a user using your method, than search for the user, delete it after the test is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to unit test code which contains calls to static methods, like `HibernateUtility.getSession()`.

You might consider injecting the Session instance (perhaps by adding a parameter to the `createUser()` method, or by giving the object that contains this method a `Session Factory` object which it can use to obtain `Session` instances). You could then use Mockito or a similar framework to provide a mock `Session` object to the method, and verify that the expected calls where being made to it.

```
public String createUser(Session session) {
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(this);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return "accountCreated";
}
```

Using Mockito, a unit test might look like this:

```
public testCreateUser(){
    Session session = mock(Session.class);
    Transaction trans = mock(Transaction.class);

    when(session.beginTransaction()).thenReturn(trans);

    obj.createUser(session);

    verify(session).save(obj);
    verify(session).close();
    verify(trans).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Can you tell me how to create mock object in java I am unable to find any Mock Class in my package ??

Comment: You will need to use a separate mocking library for this, there aren't any that come with Java out of the box. I prefer Mockito but there are many choices http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html